# Is it possible to get the Display Name back from a MVC custom model binder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

I have this code:

```
    public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {

         string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
```

modelName returns the property name, but I need to access the DisplayName, rather than the property name, for example "First Name" rather than "FirstName". Is this possible from the controllerContext or bindingContext? I couldn't find anything in the watch.

Answer (score 2):

```
string modelName = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName;
```